# Calling DocumentDb stored procedures from .net

Tags: c#, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following stored procedure that just finds an object by id.

```
function sample(id) {
    var context = getContext();
    var response = context.getResponse();
    var collection = context.getCollection();

    var findObject = "SELECT * FROM Objects o where o.userId='" + id +"'";

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        findObject,

        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (!feed || !feed.length) throw new Error("Object not found");
            else response.setBody(feed[0]);
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

And this is my C# class that extends Document

```
public class UserPoints: Document
{
    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public Guid UserId;

    [JsonProperty("remainingPoints")]
    public int RemainingPoints;
}
```

In my main function, I call the above stored procedure and expect it to return the UserPoints object for the UserId.

Eg:

```
UserPoints points = new UserPoints()
{
    UserId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    RemainingPoints = 1000
};

await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collection), points);
points.Dump();

var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<UserPoints>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(databaseName, collection, storedProcedureName), points.UserId.ToString());
response.Response.Dump();
```

I get the following exception **Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document' to type 'UserPoints'** when I execute the stored procedure

It all works fine if I just stop extending the Document base class, but then I do not have access to the SelfLink property that I need for updates. Am I doing something wrong? If ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync takes in a strong type, shouldn't it be able to type cast it and return the object of that type?

Comment: PS. you don't need SelfLink anymore for any operation in DocumentDB. You can now just use the id of the resource you are trying to refer to. For example ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("my database id", "my collection id", "my doc id"), updated_doc_object). For more info on this refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the DocumentDB .NET SDK. We're investigating a fix.

Note that as a workaround until the fix is released, you do not have to derive from Document to store documents in DocumentDB. If you need access to some of the internal properties like Id, you can add those properties to your object, e.g. as

```
 [JsonProperty("id")] public string Id {get; set;}
```